# Is the language regular or contextfree?

Tags: context-free-grammar, regular-language

Could you tell me if the language $$L=\{ w \in \{a,b,c\}^*: $$$$\text{there is at least one time the substring abc and none of the symbols a,b,c is repeated three times} \}$$ is regular or contextfree?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:**

- $D = (\Sigma^*abc\Sigma^*)$,
- $A = \overline{(\Sigma^*aaa\Sigma^*)}$ or $A = \overline{(\Sigma^*a\Sigma^*a\Sigma^*a\Sigma^*)}$ depending on the interpretation,
- $L = A \cap B \cap C \cap D$.

I hope this helps $\ddot\smile$

Comment: Nice! :) Thanks for the hint!!! So the language is regular from the closure properties?